# What is the best class for a character strong versus mind-affecting spells?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation

I am GMing a Pathfinder campaign and need to build an party NPC who is as strong as they can possibly be against mind-affecting spells and abilities. They don't need to be especially skilled in combat. Any suggestions on where to start with this?

Currently the party is level 2, but will be across a long campaign, so I need to plan for the future. Any standard race or class is fine. Anything first-party should be ok. The strong vs mind-effecting is less for combat, but more to prevent players gaining insight into their thoughts or managing to control them via suggestion or similar.

*Clarification:* The character should be one of the PHB races (human, elf, etc.) and a standard PHB class with no archetype. Cost is not a barrier.

Comment: We need more details on the constraints, level, world, available resources, and expected specific threats that they'll be wanting to fend off.

Comment: Do they need to be one of the "big 5" races?  Do they need to level along with the PCs or can they be higher? What other restrictions exist? Why mind-affecting, is this so the party doesn't control them or some external threat? Why would your party be exerting mental control over their comrades, are they evil?  Is this guy supposed to betray them at some point to where he has meaningful secrets?

Comment: No really please be more specific.

Comment: @mxyzplk Better late than never? :)

Comment: Maybe.  I'll leave it up to the jury for reopen votes.  I think it's still too unclear.  By "human, elf, etc." do you just mean PHB races, or all the first party races which include robots and androids and dhampirs?  Is accomplishing this via expensive magic item ok?  If so, how expensive?

Comment: @mxyzplk Clarified further.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your goal is to increase the will save.

My recommendation is to make the race Elf or Half-Elf or Dwarf. Elves and Half-Elves recieve +2 bonus on enchantment spells which covers most of the Mind-affecting spells. Dwarves have +2 bonus against all spells and a racial +2 wisdom to increase their will save.

As a class, I would go with Druid or Cleric if you can because those classes have a good will save progress and their main Stat is Wisdom which will net a very good Will save bonus.

Top those with [Iron Will](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/iron-will---final) and [Improved Iron Will](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/improved-iron-will---final) feats and that character will be very strong against mind affecting spells unless the caster is ridicoulusly high level or your rolls are very unlucky.

As a result, assuming you have a level 2 half-elf Cleric, with 16 Wisdom you have +10 Will(+3 Cleric,+2 Half-Elf,+2 Iron Will,+3 Wisdom) save versus Enchantment spells with a chance to reroll one once per day without any magical aid.

There are a lot more ways to incrase your mental resolve against mind affecting spells. Traits, items or playing a Paladin like *Rob* mentioned in his answer but It's difficult to deduce what is allowed in your campaign or what kind of character is suitable. I intentionally left out domains and Paladins because they are restricted to alignment or the Deity. This is quite a general approach that is suitable to any character.

Comment: Good Domain, Law Domain, Luck Domain, Protection Domain (+1 save/5 levels) would also help a Cleric

Answer (score 3):

I recommend a Half-Elf [Paladin](http://paizo.com/prd/classes/paladin.html).

This build assumes you are using background [traits](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateCampaign/characterBackground/traits.html).

My goal is to increase will save and provide resistance against enchantment magic plus add immunities whenever possible.

Build:

- 16 Charisma, 14 Wisdom
- [Iron Will](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/iron-will---final) Feat
- [Half Elf](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advancedRaceGuide/coreRaces/halfElves.html)
- Faith Trait: Disdainful Defender trait (+2 trait bonus on all Will saves you attempt against divine spells)
- Social Trait: Natural-Born Leader (+1 moral bonus for will saves vs. mind-affecting effects)

This gives:

- +10 save vs. Spells +2 (Wis) +3 (Paladin) +2 (Iron Will) +3 (Paladin Charisma Bonus)
- +12 save vs. Enchantments +2 (Wis) +3 (Paladin) +2 (Half-Elf) +2 (Iron Will) +3 (Paladin Charisma Bonus)
- +2 bonus save vs. divine spells (any kind, just not from same worshipper)
- Additional +1 vs. mind affecting spells.
- Immune to magic sleep effects (Half Elf)
- A grand total possible +15 vs divine enchantment spells.

Later on:

- 3rd Level - [Aura of Courage](http://paizo.com/prd/classes/paladin.html#aura-of-courage) Immune to fear and spells/spell like effects that cause fear.
- 8th level) [Aura of Resolve](http://paizo.com/prd/classes/paladin.html#aura-of-resolve) will make the Paladin immune to all charm spells and spell like abilities

Recommending Starting Item

- The good old [Cloak Of Resistance](http://paizo.com/prd/magicItems/wondrousItems.html#cloak-of-resistance) gives a flat bonus to all saves.